# EntityFramework 7 RC1

Tags: entity-framework

Right now I have 2 environment.

1. Dev
2. Uat

In my Uat environment, I have deploy v0.1 migrations.
In my dev I have v0.5 migrations.

1. How to generate the script migration from v0.2 -> v0.5 ONLY

> dnx ef migrations script

the above will generate the whole database script, which I only need to migration different.

2. How to rollback my database from v0.5 to v0.2?

Comment: dnx ef migrations script > v0.5.sql this will generate v0.5.sql script find INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] with value _v0.1 from top to this Insert statement remove it then apply this upgrade

Comment: for the rollback usually I perform 'dnx ef database update v0.2'. this will rollback from version v0.5 to v0.2